# ContentProvider - returning multiple Cursors or custom Object

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a working implementation of a `ContentProvider` loading data via `CursorLoader` into a listview (with custom `CursorAdapter`). It's a list of events. Every item has a title, place, etc. but also **a set of offers** which should be displayed in a `LinearLayout` inside every list row.

The problem is that a `Cursor` row can only contain flat data, not a set of other items.

My only idea is to make a joined query on database like this:

`SELECT * FROM events, offers WHERE events.id=offers.event_id;`

But then I'll have as much rows as there are offers (and the list should display events, so it's not good) and the list would be overpopulated. Maybe there is a possibility to tell `CursorAdapter` to only populate list rows with unique `events.id` but somehow retrieve the offers data as well?

The best solution would be to put a `Cursor` or custom `Object` containing offers inside the events `Cursor`. But afaik it's not possible.

Comment: I think I found the answer - MergeCursor - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html. Seems promising, but still feel free to write your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately one `CursorLoader` can only load one `Cursor`. So the solution was to write a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` which returned two `Cursors`.

Comment: Any chance you could add the Loader and CursorWrapper code to your answer? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: It's been 4 years. There are much better tools than CursorLoaders now. Try RxJava with SqlBrite for example

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. In fact, I think a lot of people are.
The whole mechanism of URI - to Relational DB through contentprovider, and everything that was built around it (like the various change listeners, file and stream handling) - this is all very impressive and useful, but for very simple data models.

Once your application needs a more elaborate data model, like - a hierarchy of tables, object relational semantics - this model breaks.
I've found a bunch of ORM tools for Android, but they seem too 'bleeding edge' to me (plus, for the life of me, I couldn't figure out if they have data change notification support).

ORM is very common today, I really hope the Android folks agree and add ORM capabilities to the platform.

This is what I ended up doing:
A cursor of cursors, with a a leading index cursor that helps choose the correct internal curosr.
It's kind of a temp solution, I just needed to move on with my code and get back to this later. Hope this helps.
Of course if you use a listview, you probably need to also create a custom adapter to inflate the correct views, and do the binding.

```
public class MultiCursor implements Cursor {
private final String        TAG             = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

ArrayList<Cursor>           m_cursors       = new ArrayList<Cursor>();
Map<Long, CursorRowPair>    m_idToCursorRow = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Long, CursorRowPair>());
Set<Long>                   m_idSet         = new HashSet<Long>();
Cursor                      m_idCursor;


/**
 * @precondition: _id column must exist on every type of cursor, and has to have index of 0 (be the first)
 * @param idCursor
 */
public MultiCursor(Cursor idCursor) {
    m_idCursor = idCursor;// this cursor binds the order (1,2,3) to ids

    // go over all the ids in id cursor and add to m_idSet
    initIdSet();

    // m_cursors.add(idCursor);
    // m_position = -1;

}


private void initIdSet() {
    m_idSet.clear();

    long id;
    m_idCursor.moveToPosition(-1);
    while (m_idCursor.moveToNext()) {
        id = m_idCursor.getLong(m_idCursor.getColumnIndex(ContentDescriptor.ShowViewItem.Cols.ID));
        m_idSet.add(id);
    }
    m_idCursor.moveToFirst();
}


public void addCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    // when something changes in the child cursor, notify parent on change, to notify subscribers
    // cursor.registerContentObserver(new SelfContentObserver(this)); // calls my onchange, which calls the ui
    m_cursors.add(cursor);
    updateIdToCursorMap(cursor);
}

private class CursorRowPair {
    public final Cursor cursor;
    public final int    row;


    public CursorRowPair(Cursor cursor, int row) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.row = row;
    }
}


private void updateIdToCursorMap(Cursor cursor) {
    // get object_type
    // for each row in cursor, take id, row number
    // add id, <cursor,rowNum> to map
    long id;
    int row = 0;
    cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContentDescriptor.ShowViewItem.Cols.ID));
        if (m_idSet.contains(id)) m_idToCursorRow.put(id, new CursorRowPair(cursor, row));
        row++;

    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}


private Cursor getInternalCursor() {
    if (getPosition() < 0 || getCount()==0) return m_idCursor; // todo throw a proper exception

    // get the id of the current row
    long id = m_idCursor.getLong(m_idCursor.getColumnIndex(ContentDescriptor.BaseCols.ID));

    CursorRowPair cursorRowPair = m_idToCursorRow.get(id);
    if (null == cursorRowPair) return null;

    Cursor cursor = cursorRowPair.cursor;
    int row = cursorRowPair.row;
    cursor.moveToPosition(row);
    return cursor;
}


// //////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public void close() {
    Log.d(TAG, "close");

    for (Cursor cursor : m_cursors) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    m_idCursor.close();
}


@Override
public void copyStringToBuffer(int columnIndex, CharArrayBuffer buffer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "copyStringToBuffer");

    getInternalCursor().copyStringToBuffer(columnIndex, buffer);
}
```

etc etc etc.

Comment: Yeah, there are lot of different Cursors (like MatrixCursor) but they didn't fit here. This solution looks nice, however a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` worked for me perfectly too.

Comment: Recently refactored my code, pulled the code above out, and did a sort of small ORMapping implementation. Created my own loaders that return List<BaseObject>, and every element type extended BaseOject.

Comment: This is exactly what I am facing... Thanks for the insight guys, and may God have mercy on my soul.

Comment: I can try and lookup my old ORM code and share it on Github, if you promise to take it forward from there :)

Answer (score 0):

In you're adapter query the offers cursor for all records and make it a class variable.  Then in your `getView` use the event id to iterate through the offer cursor and add the necessary textviews to your row layout when it find an appropriate match.  It's not elegant, but it should work.

Comment: So you suggest to have an events cursor AND also add offers cursor to the adapter? I thought about it, but unfortunately `CursorLoader` only returns one `Cursor` (obtained from `ContentProvider`). And if I return a **joined cursor** than I have too much rows. Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: Pull the cursors seperately, not as a JOIN.  The events cursors drives the population  of the list, and the offers cursor (called from inside your adapter when you start it) adds supplemental info.

Comment: Yep, but calling the offers cursor from inside of the adapter goes againt the principles of `Loaders`. It would work, but the db connection would occur on the ui thread. I think I found a solution - `MergeCursor`, but'll have to implement it first to see if it works.

Comment: Load them both outside the adapter then and make the offer cursor a `public static` so you can access it inside the adapter.